# Is there a library for converting a traceback to its exception?

Tags: python

Out of curiosity, is there a way to convert a printed traceback back to the exception that generated it or to a sys.exc_info like structure ?

Comment: By the printed traceback, do you mean a string? Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Can it`s help you ?

```
import sys
try:
    # here is your code
    number = 5/0
except Exception as e:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    raise e.with_traceback(tb)
```